# Generating sound in browser at interval

Tags: javascript, web, audio, scheduling

I would like to schedule a sound to be produced at a certain interval in a web app. A sample code is below. Please note that I also tried using Web Audio APIs with exactly the same problem I will be describing here. First, the code:

```
export default class BeepPlayer {
  constructor(interval) {
    this.audio = new Audio()
    this.audio.src = 'src/assets/sounds/metronomeClick.wav'
    this.interval = (60 / interval) * 1000
    this.intervalID = null

    console.log('interval: ' + this.interval)
  }

  play() {
    this.intervalID = setTimeout(this._playSound.bind(this), this.interval)
  }

  _playSound() {
    console.log('beep')
    this.audio.play()

    clearTimeout(this.intervalID)
    this.intervalID = setTimeout(this._playSound.bind(this), this.interval)
  }

  stop() {
    clearTimeout(this.intervalID)
    this.audio = null
  }
}
```

if I construct the object with an interval of 60, play() will sound every 1 second.

if I construct the object with an interval of 30, play() will sound every 2 seconds but skips the first beep.

if I construct the object with an interval of 20, play() will sound every 3 seconds but skips the first beep.

if I construct the object with an interval of 15, play() will not produce any sound.

I have no idea why there is a threshold at around the 3-second mark and why even the Web Audio API code which does not even load an audio file behaves the same way.

Any thoughts on how I can overcome this bizarre issue would be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: I ran that code locally, but didn't experience the problems you described; even lowering the interval to 10 resulted in regular sounds for me. Can you share a minimal reproduceable example?

Comment: it's part of a VueJS app but the test code is the following:   const bp = new BeepPlayer(15);  bp.play() I have tried it in Safari, Chrome, Brave and FF. All behave the same way. Replace 15 with 20 and it beeps but skips the first beep.Are you in Windows? but that shouldn't matter right?

Comment: @padeso, messed up my comment above. 20 (every 4 sec) works, 4 (every 15 sec)  doesn't.

Comment: Even with the interval set to 1, it plays a sound every minute for me. I highly recommend putting together a minimum reproduceable example.

Comment: codesandbox: https://jvfwrh.csb.app/ please try 20, 10, 4 and let me know the result. I'm still experiencing the same behaviour. anything above 20 is ok. 20 skips the first beep and then continues normally. anything below 20, the code runs but no sound is produced.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/intervalbeep-jvfwrh?file=/index.html in case the above link doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry, but the codesandbox code works, too. I made a small change to print the current date and time in the play and beep functions (https://codesandbox.io/s/intervalbeep-forked-j9vs27?file=/index.html:534-569), and when beep player is initialized with 4, this is the output I see:

Comment: startBeeping 
interval: 15000 
play: Fri Jul 07 2023 13:55:05 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 
beep: Fri Jul 07 2023 13:55:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 
beep: Fri Jul 07 2023 13:55:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 
beep: Fri Jul 07 2023 13:55:50 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 
beep: Fri Jul 07 2023 13:56:05 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 
beep: Fri Jul 07 2023 13:56:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 
beep: Fri Jul 07 2023 13:56:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 
beep: Fri Jul 07 2023 13:56:50 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I bet you are on Windows. I asked a friend of mine to try it and it works too (on Windows). I have no idea why it doesn't on a Mac even in different browsers or what the workaround could be. web apps are alway full of time wasters!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254401/discussion-between-padeso-and-djeetee).

Comment: FOUND THE PROBLEM! nothing to do with the OS. I had my Mac set up to play audio through external speakers via the monitor which is connected through HDMI. It's been my setup for more than 2 years and never thought of it twice. I switching to the built-in speakers and that fixed the issue. The hours I wasted one this and dragged you into it too!!! again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed. Please see my comment above. summary: use the built-in speakers of the laptop :)